# I'm looking for the simplest websocket example possible

Tags: spring-websocket

The tutorial for spring websockets brings in a whole army of technologies, and has you build a really complex chat application, but for someone who just wants the most simple possible example of web socket tech, it's way too much, without enough explanation of all the moving parts.
I have it running, and its pretty and all that, but I still don't know what STOMP is vs MQTT vs sockjs.

What I would like, is the most simple, websocket example.

Some server block that spews a string, and a very few number of lines of javascript that prints that to the console.

Then I can start to understand all this.

Can anyone point out a "hello world" spring websocket example that is much much simpler?